# How to make 20 threads to write data into csv file using java

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb, csv, java-io

I have huge data (millions of records) in mongo-db. I need to read data from one collection then do some filtering process then again matched data from another collection in mongo-db. I have to show data in a csv file (here I am using `CsvWriter`), I am able to do it as a single program/process, but it is taking lot of time (5 to 6 hours). I want to use threads.

My requirement is:

Suppose if I have 1000000 records in db then 20 threads have to distribute as 5k per thread. If have 2000000 records then 10k per thread. And also can we push data into csv file using `CsvWriter` simultaneously using 20 threads?

Comment: If the "filtering" is the bottleneck, then adding more threads may help, but if the bottleneck is the I/O, then threads won't help at all. Have you tried profiling your program to find out where it's spending its time?

Comment: yes it is taking more time after finishing filtering i.e getting matched data from DB and pushing data csv file

Comment: I would suggest making 20 temporary csv files, assigning each file to one thread and then merging them together after pulling all the data. Multithreading is a pain, and is often not worth it if the data arrives in small chunks. Multithreading only makes sense if each filter operation takes more than 250 to 500 ms. If the data needs to be in order, append the id to each entry in the temp files, and use that to sort the merged file. Then discard the id.

Comment: @Sat What did you end up using? I have to do something similar, and I wanted to know what worked for you.